# issue while adding the android project as reference to portable project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

while adding the android project as reference to portable project it is saying reference could not be added, it causes circular dependency, I have one view in android project and needs to be call from portable project, please help me in this regard.

Comment: adding an android project as a reference to a portable project is not possible. if you need to call a view from your PCL that's not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: why you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add Android project in Portable project. If you want to get any logics from android project please refer the below steps

Create interface like this in PCL

```
    public interface PortableInterface
    {
        object GetLogicFromAndroidProject();
    }
```

Add Extend this interface in your android project like below

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PortableInterfaceRenderer))]
namespace YourProjectName.iOS
{

    public class PortableInterfaceRenderer : PortableInterface
    {
        public object GetLogicFromAndroidProject()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // here write your logic 
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to call this method in PCL project

```
var obj = DependencyService.Get<PortableInterface>().GetLogicFromAndroidProject();
```

Hope this will help